# Uploading multiple images to firebase using react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, expo, firebase-storage

Am trying to uploading multiple images to firebase storage and firebase database collection using react native 'expo' but it's giving a hard time, i even tried using chatGpt but the code generated is confusing and somehow outdated so its not working.

Comment: pease add you code and what other code which you have tried this will simply us to understand you problem and resolve it...